# RE Compile giving error unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python-2.7, python-re

```
import re
import os
re_filename = re.compile(
    r"^(?:.*" + os.sep + r")?" +
    r"([^@]*?)" +
    r"(?:@([^.]*?))?" +
    r"(?:\.yang|\.yin)*" +
    r"\.(yang|yin)$")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 6, in 
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
raise error, v
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: yes. it is on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When  `os.sep` is a backslash, then it escapes the closing ")" that follows it, and so you don't have a closing parenthesis in the meaning of a capture group, but a literal ")".

So make sure the `os.sep` character is taken literally:

```
import re
import os
re_filename = re.compile(
    r"^(?:.*" + re.escape(os.sep) + r")?" +
    r"([^@]*?)" +
    r"(?:@([^.]*?))?" +
    r"(?:\.yang|\.yin)*" +
    r"\.(yang|yin)$")
```